# expressions of concentration or pH- "a solution of...." or "a solution with..."?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I wonder if the following expressions are correct. (edited)

[A]I prepared a solution such as below:

> 1. a solution of pH 3
> 2. a solution with pH 3
> 3. a solution with a pH of 3
> 4. a solution of a pH of 3

[B]I prepared a solution such as below:

> 1. a 3 nM buffer solution
> 2. a buffer solution of 3 nM
> 3. a buffer solution of 3 nM concentration
> 4. a buffer solution with a concentration of 3 nM
> 5. a buffer solution of a concentration of 3 nM

I'm not a native speaker and confused.  Especially, can I use [B]-2 or 3 expressions?

Comment: I think you should add context to your examples because it seems both prepositions are legitimate for making such phrases. Also, you should mention what do you think yourself. (I have no idea about the last two examples)

Comment: BTW, I think nM stands for nanomolar. If that's the case I cannot understand "a solution with 3 nM"!

Comment: I mean you need an element after **nM**- with 3 nM Sio2.

Comment: How about the expression in the right?   3 nM Sio2 --> Sio2 of 3 nM.     I think nM can stand for nanomole as well as nanomolar. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

A3 ("a solution with a pH of 3") sounds most natural to my (American) ear.  The other three choices are also understandable.

B1 ("a 3 nM buffer solution") and B4 ("a buffer solution with a concentration of 3 nM") sound natural to me.  The other choices could sound natural, if they are followed by a prepositional phrase saying what the 3 nM consists of.

Comment: Thank you very much~.  Because the formal expressions are too long, I would like to change them to more compact expressions as below: (1) a solution with a pH of 3 --> a solution of pH 3; (2)a buffer solution with a concentration of 3 nM --> a buffer solution of 3 nM. But I'm not sure if I can use these expressions in a formal document such as an chemistry article of a journal.  If I have hundreds of solutions to describe, I would need to use a more simple expression, if correct.

Comment: [@DEAD](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/14111) or another chemist might know what phrasings are normal in chemistry journals.

Comment: If you are planning to publish an article in a journal, you probably work with people who have already done so.  Can you ask them?

Comment: Sure. But they are all Asians and not so reliable..

Comment: I'd suggest consulting the journal you plan to publish the paper in. Look for examples in papers they've already published which are similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

> a solution of pH 3

This sounds like the solution was engineered/created/intended to have pH 3.

> a solution with pH 3

This sounds like a solution was located somewhere, the pH was tested, then found to be 3.